# How to resolve env variables in pipenv scripts [Windows OS]

Tags: windows, docker, powershell, pipenv

I want to use something like below:

```
[scripts]
docker_build = "docker build --build-arg PYPI_CREDS=$env:PYPI_CREDS -t myimage:latest ."
```

Whereas `PYPI_CREDS` has already been defined and loaded by pipenv from `.env` file.
I am using windows OS.

Now, it is not able to resolve the env variable passed in `docker_build` script while running it like `pipenv run docker_build`

Any solution for this?

Also asked here: https://github.com/pypa/pipenv/issues/3901#issuecomment-952131124

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you've confirmed, `pipenv` uses `cmd.exe`, not PowerShell, to launch command lines.

Therefore, you must use `cmd.exe`'s syntax to refer to environment variable `PYPI_CREDS`, namely `%PYPI_CREDS%` (rather than PowerShell's syntax, `$env:PYPI_CREDS`):

```
[scripts]
docker_build = "docker build --build-arg PYPI_CREDS=%PYPI_CREDS% -t myimage:latest ."
```